# How to debug Javascript in webstorm when gulp is serving the application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, gulp, webstorm

In Webstorm, I am running gulp serve task that launches localhost:9000 stub angular project generated with yo. 
I am trying to debug JavaScript code and this is what i have tried:

- I run gulp as a debug task, I can only debug gulp file lines
- I try to run gulp serve before JavaScript, it starts serving and Webstorm never gets to launching its JavaScript debug session
- I try to run JavaScript debug, I don't get breakpoints inside my code.

What is the workflow in this situation?

PS. i am not trying to debug code inside chrome developer tools, i want my breakpoints to work in Webstorm

Comment: Have you tried putting debugger; in with console open?

Comment: I don't believe i have, how do i do that?

Comment: you mean the script line, that breaks inside chrome. that is what i would like to avoid as I'm trying to use native debugging capabilities of webstorm

Comment: I just put it in an answer for you, @RIAwolf

Comment: If you don't want to use debugger or console.log() - I am not sure what you're looking for. As far as I know, Webstorm is not aware of the app running in another application.

Comment: there is jetbrains plugin for chrome and firefox that intercepts session and send data directly to IDE. i have done this successfully without gulp. Please respond only if you use gulp and Webstorm breakpoints inside javascript

Comment: what code are you trying to debug - server-side code (gulp serve task), or client-side code (your AngularJS application served by Gulp)? In the latter case, you need using JavaScript Debug run configuration with Remote URL mappings - see https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Starting+a+JavaScript+debug+session#StartingaJavaScriptdebugsession-Startingadebugsessionwhenusingadifferentwebserver

Comment: did that, gulp serve task launches serving, then javascript debuger should start, but it doesnt happen, i went through these documents multiple times and i have been using intellij products for years, which is why this is so baffeling, my setup should work, but it doesnt

Answer (score 1):

In your Javascript - put `debugger;` between two of your lines, and pop open your `Developer Tools` in Chrome. When you refresh the page - if your script runs, it should stop where you put the `debugger;` and you'll be able to hover on different variables to see their values. Very powerful and basic tool.

Also, if you don't want to have the script stop - you can `console.log(variable);` to have the Developer Tools console print out the variable.

Example:

```
var somethingOrOther = function(){
var blah = 'foo';
console.log(blah);// to print to console
debugger; // to stop script at this point and look around
};
```

Don't forget to remove the `debugger;` when you're done.
I recommend using `jshint` in your gulp to make sure you don't miss those kinds of things.

Comment: I need to break code inside webstorm IDE with its integrated debugger.

Comment: Ah - sorry, I haven't used it - but here's the docs which I'm sure you've seen already. https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/debugging-javascript.html#d274901e534

Comment: Yes, it works when you are not using gulp for serving, however these days its not the workflow developers use

Comment: This does not really answer the question. U could use debugger without WebStorm