# How to debug an AngularJS(Angular 1.x)/Gulp application in WebStorm's debugger so that client side JS breakpoints work in WebStorm?

Tags: angularjs, debugging, gulp, webstorm

I've followed numerous documents/tutorials to no avail. It looks like someone in the past asked a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313401/how-to-debug-javascript-in-webstorm-when-gulp-is-serving-the-application) but it was not answered exactly but that was two years ago.

Comment: Afaik, you can't - they're client-side.

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-angular-apps/ ?

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS application running/debugging doesn't differ from any other javascript client-side application running/debugging: you need a [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) run configuration for this. The way your Angular application is served (via a custom node.js server, Gulp, WebStorm built-in web server or any other web server) matters nothing - you just have to specify your application URL (the one you use to access it in browser) as **URL** in your Run configuration.
see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html, *Debugging an application running on an external web server*

Comment: Tried this and seems to me you can then just debug the compiled JS, so "after gulp". Would be nice to have breakpoints in pre-compiled code and have these working. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: must be a problem with sourcemaps - they are either missing or not accurate, so the sources can't be mapped to the compiled code being run. make sure to that `'gulp-sourcemaps'` package is used and configured properly